# Compile production assets from clojurescript with figwheel

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

We currently use cljsbuild to compile our clojurescript source into the assets used in production, but during development, we use lein-figwheel. Both cljsbuild and figwheel are constantly watching for changes of the source and recompile when necessary.

I was wondering, whether it's possible to use just one tool for both, preferably in the same process.

We're fine with switching tools, especially Figwheel Main. Each file change should just compile:

- a js with advanced optimizations to be used in production
- live reload the code in the browser as figwheel & figwheel main do it

I found [this](https://figwheel.org/tutorial.html#packaging-up-a-single-compiled-artifact-for-production) in the figwheel documentation, but it requires manual work like cleaning targets and running the build on demand with special options.

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched from `lein-figwheel` to `figwheel-main` (using Clojure Deps in place of `lein`). Figwheel-Main is much simpler, easier & better (basically it is "Figwheel 2.0").

Figwheel-Main can be used for both the auto-reloading during development and for compiling a single `my-app.js` output file for deployment or testing.  You can use either `:whitespace` or `:advanced` compiler optimization level to get a single static `*.js` output file.  I use `:whitespace` to generate an output file for standalone testing purposes (in Docker with `chrome --headless`) or `:advanced` for the final production build.

As a side benefit, Clojure Deps is better than `lein` for managing conflicting dependency versions.